# What are the draw backs If I will increase the pagesize while syncing(incremental sync) from azure service

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, azure-mobile-services

While doing syncing from Azure, I am doing like this

```
MSPullSettings *pullSettings = [[MSPullSettings alloc] initWithPageSize:500];
[self.table  pullWithQuery:query queryId:[super getQueryIdForQuery:@"allCustomers"] settings:pullSettings
                    completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                        //Let the caller know that we have finished
                        if (completion != nil) {
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                completion(error);
                            });
                        }
                    }];
```

Referring to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-how-to-use-client-library).

I know the default page size is 50 by Azure.
I observed that If I am giving more page size(1000) for 1000 records then it's taking less time than page size(50) for 1000 records.

Suppose I don't know how many records on my server, So I am giving maximum page size to get better performance.

But here my question is,
Is there any drawback for increased page size? (i.e for 50 records page size is 1000)

Or

Is there any way to know how many records in the server before giving page size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PageSize is property to get number of records from server into sync table in 1 request go. There is no drawback in increasing PageSize to 1000 if you response data size is not considerably more. One important thing is that if you increase the client page size to 1000, you should also increase the page size on the server to 1000. Also make sure server PageSize should always be more than client PageSize.